# Android: app cant ping device on wifi network when connecting in the app

Tags: android, socket.io, network-programming, wifi, wifimanager

I have built an app using Socket.io and android network discovery. when the server is started and the android device resolves the service i attempt to create a socket, but it never works on first try. I have to kill the app and restart it and then it works fine.
The server is running on the access point. the connection to the network is fine but i cannot ping the server. But as mentioned before if i kill the app and run it again it works fine.

---

**Eidt 2**

After further debugging I narrowed the crash down to any time my app sets up the wifi connection. the ssid and and password are obtained from a qrcode and the app sets up the wifi connection.

---

**read qr code data**

```
        @Override
        public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<Barcode> detections) {
            final SparseArray<Barcode> barCodes = detections.getDetectedItems();

            if (!receivedDetection) {
                if (barCodes.size() != 0) {

                    Log.i(TAG, "received a Barcode");
                    receivedDetection = true;

                    Gson g = new Gson();
                    try {
                        barCodeData = g.fromJson(barCodes.valueAt(0).rawValue, AccessPointCredentials.class);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        barCodeData = new AccessPointCredentials();
                        barCodeData.setSsid(barCodes.valueAt(0).rawValue);
                        barCodeData.setPass(null);
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    connectToWifi(barCodeData);

                }
            }
        }
```

**connectToWifi()**

```
private void connectToWifi(final AccessPointCredentials credentials) {

    new AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object>() {
        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object... objects) {
            WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) mActivity.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

            wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
            int netId;

            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                ie.printStackTrace();
            }

            for (WifiConfiguration tmp : wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks()) {
                if (tmp.SSID.equals("\"" + credentials.getSsid() + "\"")) {

                    netId = tmp.networkId;
                    boolean enabled = wifiManager.enableNetwork(netId, true);

                    Log.i(TAG, "doInBackground: Enabled? " + enabled);

                    mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            mActivity.onBackPressed();
                        }
                    });
                    return null;
                }
            }


            final String[] apSettings = {credentials.getSsid(), credentials.getPass()};
            final WifiConnect WifiTask = new WifiConnect(mActivity);
            mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    WifiTask.execute(apSettings);
                }
            });
            this.cancel(true);
            return null;
        }

        @TargetApi(23)
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Object aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

            if (Build.VERSION.RELEASE.equalsIgnoreCase("6.0")) {
                if (!Settings.System.canWrite(mActivity)) {
                    Intent goToSettings = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS);
                    goToSettings.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + mActivity.getPackageName()));
                    mActivity.startActivity(goToSettings);
                } else {
                    bindToNetwork();
                }


            } else {
                bindToNetwork();
            }
        }
    }.execute();
}
```

**bindToNetwork()**

```
private void bindToNetwork() {
    final ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) mActivity.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkRequest.Builder builder;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        builder = new NetworkRequest.Builder();
        //set the transport type do WIFI
        builder.addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI);
        connectivityManager.requestNetwork(builder.build(), new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onAvailable(Network network) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    connectivityManager.bindProcessToNetwork(network);

                } else {
                    //This method was deprecated in API level 23
                    ConnectivityManager.setProcessDefaultNetwork(network);
                }
                try {
                    //do a callback or something else to alert your code that it's ok to send the message through socket now
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                connectivityManager.unregisterNetworkCallback(this);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

**Edit**

the boolean method isServerReachable() trows an exception

`java.net.SocketException: socket failed: ENONET (Machine is not on the network)`

---

```
public boolean isServerReachable(){

        boolean isReachable;
        try {
            isReachable = InetAddress.getByName(mService.getHost().getHostAddress()).isReachable(5000);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            isReachable = false;
        }
        Log.i(TAG, "onServiceResolved: Server reachable? " + String.valueOf(isReachable));

        Log.i(TAG, "onServiceResolved: Is Network online? " + String.valueOf(isNetworkOnline()));

    if (isReachable){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it but I am not convinced it is the best solution and will accept a better one if it added.

I modified the for loop in the `connectToWifi()` method  by adding a `Thread.sleep(500);` call after `wifiManager.enableNetwork()` and it is now working.

```
for (WifiConfiguration tmp : wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks()) {
    if (tmp.SSID.equals("\"" + credentials.getSsid() + "\"")) {
        netId = tmp.networkId;
        boolean enabled = wifiManager.enableNetwork(netId, true);

        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            ie.printStackTrace();
        }

        mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mActivity.onBackPressed();
            }
        });
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the symptoms it looks like you expect wifiManager.enableNetwork() call to be blocking, but in fact it isn't. So you call isServerReachable() before the network is actually connected.

You can find a good description of what to do in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5264739/android-wifimanager-always-returns-true) (first answer).

Comment: That makes sence but how come even if i call `isServerReachable()` or try to interact with the server later it is still not reachable. the issue appears to be fixed after i put a `Thread.sleep(500);` call after `wifiManager.enableNetwork()` and it works but i feel this might not be the best way to solve the issue.